# OneHotEncoding Protein Sequences

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bioinformatics, one-hot-encoding

I have an original dataframe of sequences listed below and am trying to use one-hot encoding and then store these in a new dataframe, I am trying to do it with the following code but am not able to store because I get the following output afterwards:

Code:

```
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
sequence = np.array(list(x_train['sequence'])).reshape(-1, 1)
encoded_sequence = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(sequence).toarray()
encoded_sequence
```

[image]

but get error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 12755, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that strange array because it treats every sequence as an entry and tries to one-hot encode it, we can use an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':['AQAVPW','AMAVLT','LDTGIN']})

enc = OneHotEncoder()
seq = np.array(df['sequence']).reshape(-1,1)
encoded = enc.fit(seq)
encoded.transform(seq).toarray()

array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])

encoded.categories_

[array(['AMAVLT', 'AQAVPW', 'LDTGIN'], dtype=object)]
```

Since your entries are unique, you get this all zeros matrix. You can understand this better if you use pd.get_dummies

```
pd.get_dummies(df['sequence'])

  AMAVLT AQAVPW LDTGIN
0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   0   1
```

There's two ways to do this, one way is to simply count the amino acid occurrence and use that as a predictor, I hope I get the amino acids correct (from school long time ago):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

pd.DataFrame([ProteinAnalysis(i).count_amino_acids() for i in df['sequence']])

    A   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   K   L   M   N   P   Q   R   S   T   V   W   Y
0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

The other is to split the sequences, and do this encoding by position, and this requires the sequences to be equally long, and that you have enough memory:

```
byposition = df['sequence'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))
byposition

    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   A   Q   A   V   P   W
1   A   M   A   V   L   T
2   L   D   T   G   I   N

pd.get_dummies(byposition)

    0_A 0_L 1_D 1_M 1_Q 2_A 2_T 3_G 3_V 4_I 4_L 4_P 5_N 5_T 5_W
0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
2   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you for answering with such detail. This is really incredible, I really appreciate it. I didn't even consider the last part to be honest, looks like pretty cool stuff. Each one of my sequences is generally about 300-305bp long.

Comment: I was looking at the pd.get_dummies() but I really want to look at each position of the sequence, and this is quite ideal. I have a question though for the count_amino_acids. Does it take consideration if our sequence has gaps "aa-aa-ca" for example.

Comment: count_amino_acids should take "-" as missing. I tried ```pd.Series(ProteinAnalysis("AA-QVT").count_amino_acids()).sum()``` and it gives 5. You might need to check again for all your sequences